# How do I define a state jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, state

```
 $(document).on("click", '.gifyImage', function(event) {
    var clickedImage = $(event.target);
    if(clickedImage.data('state') === "animate") {
        //set to still
        clickedImage.data('state', "still");
        // update state clickedImage.data('state', 'animate');
        clickedImage.data('state', "animate");
    } else {
        //set to animate
        clickedImage.data('state', "animate");
        //update state to still
        clickedImage.data('state', "still");
    }
    clickedImage.attr('src', clickedImage.data('still'));
    console.log(event.target);
})

gifImage.data(state, 'animate');
```

^^^ that is the so called error i'm getting when i open up my dev tools

Backstory to why i'm writing this function.. I have a assignment that requires me to have the gif image still and when clicked on the gif it will start to play (animate), and when i click it again it will go back to being still. This code here is giving me a error : "State is not defined"
[the error im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGdWg.png)

Comment: The error says `State is not defined` but there is not even one reference to a variable called `State` in your code. Are you sure you are getting that error for this code?

Comment: Can you say which line gives you that error? Because I don't think it should and I don't get that error myself when I try it.

Comment: I have added the error im getting

Comment: It does sound like you have missed some quotes `.data(state, ...` somewhere, but not in the provided code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line

```
        gifImage.data(state, 'animate');
```

put `state` into quotes:

```
        gifImage.data('state', 'animate');
```

Comment: omg. Thank you.. i feel stupid! I'm new to this jquery and javascript stuff

Comment: stuff like this happens to everyone of us, so don't worry …